# Visual-small size language

Tags: windows, visual-studio, user-interface, lazarus

I need to develop a simple Windows application with 6 or 7 forms. Its main purpose is to manage files and launch a external program.

These are my wishes, in descending importance order

1. Free
2. Be Visual, I mean, the possibility to paint forms and object in the screen.
3. Possibility to carry it in a USB pen-drive.

I need a light/small size language, not a very complex one. My program is going to have very few forms and its functionality is simple.

Is there any language that meet this wishes? If not, is there any commercial one?

Answer (score 4):

I would use [Visual C# Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/) if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, C# isn't a bad choice.

Personally I'd use [wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115495/is-python-any-good-for-gui-development/115654#115654). If you want a GUI to help you lay out the forms, [wxDesigner](http://www.roebling.de/) is very good.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Visual Basic Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vb/Default.aspx). IMNTBHO, the learning curve for VB.Net is shallower than the C# equivalent.

Failing that (as much as it pains me to say this) take a look at MS-Access (and a runtime install for carrying it around with you). It's not free, but it's also not terribly expensive. The learning curve is even shallower than VB.Net.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned wanting your program to be portable on a USB drive, so the previous answers suggesting C# and VB.Net are good as long as all of the machines you'll be using your program on have the .Net framework installed.

If you need to run your program on systems without .Net, you'll need to look at programming environments that can either make a native .exe or can wrap scripts in an executable.  Which of those is right depends on your needs and programming experience, but I'd take a look at [Lazarus/Free Pascal](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/), [C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/default.aspx), or [Python](http://www.python.org/) (with [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)).

Comment: +1 for py2exe - the executables it generates aren't particularly small but it's an excellent way to package an application for clients who don't/won't have Python installed.

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for Lazarus/Free Pascal. It works from stick, and generates (on Windows 32/64/CE) standalone binaries, and you have full access to the windows api and other windwos specific gadgets (COM)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Express editions seems good for your requirement.

Check: http://www.microsoft.com/Express/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [Turbo Explorer](http://www.codegear.com/downloads/free/turbo). It's a free RAD IDE that'll generate native win32 apps in C++ or Delphi without the need for a managed framework like .NET.

It couldn't be simpler to use. Just drag and drop your components on your form, compile, and run.

Comment: Turbo Explorer isn't available any longer, when Embarcadero took over, they stopped issueing keys (in 2007 or so). Due to its limitations afaik you also can't do the minor Vista/W7 compatibility updates that you can do if you have the real thing. But for Eur 100 there is Delphi XE starter

Answer (score 0):

I'd ordinarily push for C# or something on the .NET framework but the stipulation of running on a flash disk means you need something that compiles natively. In addition to Lazarus/FreePascal mentioned above you might also want to investigate [CodeGear Delphi](http://www.codegear.com/products/delphi)

Comment: (The last free version of Delphi is already quite old, and the from-stick support is only in the last paid version, so I doubt this will work. 

It is always good to install the free Delphi product (Turbo Explorer, based on D2006) though if you start with Lazarus/FPC. For compatibility testing, and some forms of debugging etc)

Comment: He stipulated that commercial software too would be acceptable which is why I suggested Delphi

Comment: Only when there is no alternative. And there _is_ a free version of Delphi. Moreover, even for a commercial product, retail Delphi is in a quite stiff price category (compared to other commercial tools for home use like e.g. the $50 Real basic), which IMHO puts it outside normal homeuse scope.